# Unite.vim : Use "ag" to search all files in all subdirectories, and navigate the results

Tags: vim

I see lots of ways to show the list of all files and do fuzzy-search, and ways to search open files, but can I search all files for a string and them navigate the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link [here](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher#vim) explaining how to use `ag` with the [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) plugin (also available from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572)). That's probably your fastest solution but I don't know any more about it.

I'm not familiar with `ag` either, but the general idea to using some tool other than `grep` to perform a search within `Vim` as the `:grep` command does is to find a set of options to your tool that make your tool behave like `grep -n`, then set 'grepprg' to that string. See

```
:help 'greprg'
:help :grep
```

If the output of your tool is not sufficiently close to that of `grep`, you may have to fiddle with the 'grepformat' option. See

```
:help 'grepformat'
```